# Frobenius theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

I came across the following conclusion in a textbook, but can't really understand it. I would be grateful if anyone could elaborate:

Assume that we have two linearly independent vector fields $V_{1},V_{2}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Then,for a function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$,

*if* $[V_{1},V_{2}]=0$ *and* $V_{1}f=0$, $V_{2}f=0$, *it follows from the Frobenius theorem that* $f$ *is a function of one variable*.

I only have a basic understanding of Frobenius theorem, namely, if the vector fields $V_{i}$ are linearly independent and commute, then a PDE system $V_{i}f=0$ is solvable. But how do I get "function of one variable" statement?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You wrote *three* where you meant *two*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Frobenius theorem implies that you can find a chart which has $V_1=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}$ and $V_2=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}$, so locally your $f$, which is a function of $(x^1,x^2,x^3)$, is such that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^1}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^2}=0.$$
Of course, this means that (in an appropriate neighborhood of each point) $f$ depends only on $x^3$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As a follow up: would the same be true if the commutator of $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$ was a linear combination of $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$?

Comment: @GregVoit, in that case  $V_1$ and $V_2$ are everywhere tangent to a family of surfaces (the distribution is integrable), and $f$ is constant on each of those surfaces. You can still choose coordinates so that these surfaces are given by $x^3=\text{constant}$ and $f$ will depend just on $x^3$.

Comment: as a follow up question: is it equivalent to say that there is a coordinate system, say $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})$, such that $V_{1}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}}$ and $V_{2}=g(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}}+h(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2}}$? @TedShifrin

Comment: or does it have to be in the exact form $V_{1}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}}$ and $V_{2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2}}$? @TedShifrin

Comment: @GregVoit, the former. The latter can happen only when the Lie bracket is $0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I see. Just to make sure I understood correctly: If the Lie bracket is zero, then *both* options are possible, i.e. $V_{1}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}}$, $V_{2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2}}$ and $V_{1}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}}$, $V_{2}=g\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}}+h\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2}}$. Right?

Comment: @TedShifrin could you maybe clarify?